# XSL Select value of both attribute AND element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm working on an XSL stylesheet for some XML encoded finding aids. At the detailed description level for the contents of the collection, I have some containers like so:

```
<container type="folder">1</container>
```

I need to select both the @type AND the number value in the container, however all I can manage to pull is the number. How should I structure my query to get `folder 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If current node is container:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(@type, ' ', text())"/>
```

Input XML:

```
<container type="folder">1</container>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="container">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(@type, ' ', text())"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
folder 1
```

Comment: Works beautifully. Thanks! I never remember concat.